# Why am i getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to write an **ajax** web app. I have a function that is suppose to request a **json** object and then use it to re/populate the website.

Here is the **Javascript** in Question **(Lines 8 - 16)**:

```
window.onload=LoadData("Home", {});
var _doc = {};
function LoadData(page, params) {
    $.get(page, params, function ( data ) { 
        _doc = jQuery.parseJSON( data ); 
        }
    );
    document.title = _doc.Title.Title;
};
```

Here is the error **Chrome** gave:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined
LoadDatahttp://127.0.0.1/:15
(anonymous function)
```

This is what has me confused if I run the same statement in the console:

```
document.title = _doc.Title.Title;
"Home"
```

And it changes the title to Home

Here is proof that its not undefined:

```
_doc
Object
   Body: Object
      Menus: Array[4]
         0: Object
            Menu: Object
         1: Object
            Menu: Object
         2: Object
            Menu: Object
         3: Object
            Menu: Object
   Title: Object
      Title: "Home"
   User: Object
      Name: "Username"
```

And A screenshot as an overview:
[image: This is What the Chrome Console Looks Like...]
**Note: the call to the function at the bottom did change the title**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only access the `data` from the AJAX request in the callback:

```
window.onload=LoadData("Home", {});
var _doc = {};
function LoadData(page, params) {
    $.get(page, params, function ( data ) { 
          _doc = jQuery.parseJSON( data ); 
          document.title = _doc.Title.Title;
        }
    ));
};
```

AJAX requests (**Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML) requests are asynchronous; the browser initiates the request, and **does not** wait for a response... instead the JavaScript execution is continued. *Some time later*, when the HTTP request for the AJAX request has completed, the callback you provided for the AJAX request is invoked, and has access to the data contained in the HTTP response.

In your situation, `document.title = _doc.Title.Title;` is executed **immediately** after the AJAX request is dispatched (i.e. before the **some time later** mentioned above has occured); so the callback `_doc = jQuery.parseJSON( data );` has not fired yet, so `_doc` is still an empty object, so `_doc.Title` is undefined, and trying to retrieve `Title` on the undefined `_doc.Title` is throwing the error.

Unrelated to your problem, but FYI, you might want to look at the [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON) method; the difference between that that the `jQuery.get` method is that the response object you get passed will *already* be the JSON object (so you won't need to call `jQuery.parseJSON`).

Answer (score 0):

Your `$.get()` function is asynchronous.  That means that when you call it, all you are doing is STARTING the execution of the ajax call.  Thus, the line following it:

```
document.title = _doc.Title.Title;
```

is executing BEFORE the ajax call has completed.  You only know the ajax call has completed in it's completion function.

To fix this, put the reference to `_doc` in the ajax completion function:

```
window.onload=LoadData("Home", {});
var _doc = {};
function LoadData(page, params) {
    $.get(page, params, function ( data ) { 
        _doc = jQuery.parseJSON( data ); 
        document.title = _doc.Title.Title;
        }
    );
};
```