# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined when querying SharePoint list

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to return a result from SharePoint list to a HTML page. I'm using code which I've used successfully below, but in this instance it's not returning the results.

Using Console I'm getting the 'Uncaught TypeError' and this post is edging me towards a solution: [Why am i getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113985/why-am-i-getting-this-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-title-o)  but I don't know where I should put the Ajax function.

Here's the JavaScript if anyone can make a suggestion?

```
 var call = $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }       
    });
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
        var KnownTitle = item.Title;
```

JSON

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [{
      "__metadata": {
        "uri": "collaboration-dev.nogine.com/sites/it/SstemInventory/_vti_in/…\"1\"",
        "type": "M‌​icrosoft.SharePointDataService.KnownisuesItem"
      },
      "Title": "etwork Issue",
      "IssueID": 1
    }, {
      "__metadata": {
        "uri": "collaboration-dev.‌​norgine.com/sites/it‌​/SystemInventory/_vt‌​i_bin/…\"1\"",
        "type": "Microsoft.SharePont.DataService.KnowissuesItem"
      },
      "Title"‌​: "Door problem",
      "IssueID": 2
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: share your JSON Structure

Comment: Where would I find that?

Comment: Add console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); inside done function

Comment: So paste 'console.log(JSON.stringify(data));' into the call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR) line?

Comment: yes before $.each. Then share the output from console

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting:

 {"d":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"uri":"http://collaboration-xxx.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Knownissues(1)","etag":"W/\"1\"","type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.KnownissuesItem"},"Title":"Network Issue","IssueID":1},{"__metadata":{"uri":"http://collaboration-xxx.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Knownissues(2)","etag":"W/\"1\"","type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.KnownissuesItem"},"Title":"Door problem","IssueID":2}]}}

Comment: Does the JSON mean much?